# Postfix - write the Log of the particular mailId contents and remove it

Tags: shell, postfix

I need to write a log file that will be contain all mail contents of the particular mail id from the mail queue.

I have written the below code that will be shown the all mailID.

```
mailq | tail -n +2 | awk 'BEGIN { RS = "" } / root@'+`hostname`+'$/ { print $1 }'
```

example: my hostname as **test.com** the above query will be shows the all mail queue ID of the **root@test.com**

**Output:**
like that

```
295E36A10B7
270986A1407
26F296A1460
9099D6A02F8
```

but i will try the following query for showing the content of the mailqueue ID. That's not working.

```
for i in mailq | tail -n +2 | awk 'BEGIN { RS = "" } / root@'+`hostname`+'$/ { print $1 }' ; do postcat -q $i >> maillog.log; postsuper -d $i; done ;
```

that not working. could you please give an idea for showing the all mail contents.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have tried the below solution. That's working fine.

```
array=($(mailq | tail -n +2 | awk 'BEGIN { RS = "" } / root@'+`hostname`+'$/ { print $1 }'));
for i in ${array[@]}; 
do 
postcat -q $i >> maillog.log;
 postsuper -d $i; 
done
```